# Encrypt XML Configuration file while publishing the Window form application from visual studio

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, encryption, publish

I have XML configuration file for my window form application. I need to encrypt this file using a method (already have) every time when i publish it using click once. So that in the deployed version of tool, user would not be able to read that xml file. I have used **BeforePublish** with reference  from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366724.aspx

**I have added below lines in .csproj File**

```
<UsingTask TaskName="TestProject.SimpleTask" AssemblyName="TestProject" TaskFactory="SimpleTask" />
<Target Name="BeforePublish">
   <SimpleTask />
</Target>
```

**And added a new class like below:**

```
public class SimpleTask : Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Task
{
   public override bool Execute()
   {
      File.WriteAllText(@"D:\test.txt", "Working");
      //Will add code to encrypt xml file here
      return true;
   }
}
```

But when i try to publish the application it gives below error:

```
The task factory "SimpleTask" could not be loaded from the assembly "TestProject". Could not load file or assembly 'TestProject' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

SimpleTask is not dependent on any other dll. Please help me out here.
if there is some other solution to the same problem, please suggest that as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You know, if your application can decrypt the file then a smart user can too. I assume you are using DPAPI? That is not intended to hide things from the authenticated user, it is meant to hide things from others that may log in to the same pc or get file system access to it.

Comment: I am using rijndaelmanaged for encrypting file. However I need to call a method before as soon as publish event is triggered from visual studio.

Comment: I have used custom build tasks before but not with click once. I use this attribute in the `UsingTask`: `AssemblyFile="$(ProjectDir)\folder_if_any\your_assembly.dll\` . It may also work if you sign the assembly and install it in the GAC.

Comment: @Crowcoder, as it is a winform application, .dll is not there in Project\bin\debug , instead i have .exe... Can i give path of .exe as assembly... ?

Comment: Your build task is a winforms app? I don't know if that would work, I wouldn't expect you want user interaction to be required in the middle of a publish, but I guess it might be possible. However, if you are storing the encryption key locally then you have the same problem as DPAPI - if the app can decrypt then so can the user. If this is really sensitive information then the operation should be sent to a secure server for processing, like via a web api or something.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding AssemblyFile attribute, here you can specify the path to assembly:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="TestProject.SimpleTask" AssemblyName="TestProject" 
TaskFactory="SimpleTask" AssemblyFile="c:\path\to\assembly\TestProject.exe" />
```